# Печать Google Map на сайте

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps, печать

Необходимо на сайте распечатать карту.
При печати отображается почти все необходимое, кроме карты. Маркеры видео отлично и расстояние. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
function initialize() {
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.840187, 35.137507),
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

if($(window).width() < 1000)
{
    mapOptions.draggable = false;
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#map-canvas'), mapOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

@media print {
.noprint {
    display: none;
}
#map-canvas {   
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 914px;
    height: 616px;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    print-color-adjust: exact;
}
#noprint {
    display: none;
}
```

}

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="map">
                        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
                            <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <form class="calculator-form ">
                                    <div class="form-section">
                                        <div class="address-inputs">
                                            <div class="distance-preview">
                                                <span class="value">00</span><br>
                                                <span class="measure">Км</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <label for="from" class="text-label">
                                                <input type="text" class="fromAddr" name="from" placeholder="Пункт А" autocomplete="off" id="fromAddr" >
                                            </label><br>
                                            <label for="to" class="text-label">
                                                <input type="text" class="toAddr" name="to" placeholder="Пункт В" autocomplete="off" id="toAddr">
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Приведите версию гуглапи, и листинг того как вы создаёте объект карты. Ну ничего же не понятно.

Comment: Попробую наванговать, что для отображения карты используется `background`, который при печати намеренно скрывается браузером. Правда, как исправить, не знаю

Comment: Есть вариант отрисовать содержимое страницы на какое нибудь полотно, и предлагать на печать содержимое этого полотна. Посмотрите образец: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf

Answer (score 1):

Разверни дополнительные параметры и включи печать фона:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Наверно это решение, но, боюсь, каждого пользователя сайта трудно заставить это делать